# PHP script for adding data to database not working

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I have  a php script to input data to a database *list* in table ***listdata***.

Here is the code for my view.

```
<form action="../add.php" method="post">

            <label for="title">Title:</label>
            <br>
            <input id="title" type="text" name="title"/>

            <br>

            <label for="body">Body:</label>
            <br>
            <textarea name="body" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>

            <br>

            <input id="sb" type="submit" values="Add">
</form>
```

and here is my controller (no framework)

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
include 'views/add.view.php';

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'post') {
            $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=list', $config['username'], $config['password']);
            $title = $_POST['title'];
            $body = $_POST['body'];
    if (empty($title) or empty($body)) {
        $status = "<h3>Enter Values</h3>";
        echo $status;
    } else {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO listdata(title,body) VALUES(:title,:body)');
        $stmt->bindParam(':title',$title);
        $stmt->bindParam(':body',$body);
        $stmt->execute();
        $status =  "<h3 message='id'>Added<h3>";
        echo $status;
    }



}



?>
```

When I run it in the browser , before or after posting the values , there is no error , but the `$status` variable is not being echoed and the database is not being updated.

Comment: Are you sure it is getting into the first if statement? echo something to make sure you are even getting that far because I suspect you are not

Comment: @Chitowns24 Thank you for finding me another error : IT ' doesen't echo , what do I do?

Comment: Let's `echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` because `===` means exactly equal and it may not just be 'post'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try change your controller to:

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
include 'views/add.view.php';

    if ($_POST) {
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=list', $config['username'], $config['password']);
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $body = $_POST['body'];
       if (empty($title) || empty($body))
       {
           $status = "<h3>Enter Values</h3>";
       }
       else
       {
           $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO listdata(title, body) VALUES(:title, :body)');
           $stmt->execute(array(':title'=>$title, ':body'=>$body));
           $status =  "<h3 message='id'>Added<h3>";
       }
       echo $status;
}

?>
```

Comment: Instead of checking the request method, he checked to see if there were any POST variables

Comment: thats why i used simple $_POST check,

Comment: <pre><code>if ($_POST)</code></pre> , this is why is still code